# Does anybody know what is the timing of 'under the bridge' guitar intro riff?

Tags: guitar, rhythm

Not sure how do I count the Under the bridge chord riff (starting with E major). I think I can play it right and I can feel the sort of the song and play but when I start to count I am not sure if I am counting right. 
I count to 5 beats but the chord embellishments seem to be falling off beat somehow. 
I am confused. please can anybody enlightenment me.

Comment: The version I listened to starts on D. Then to F#. All in 4/4 time, slowly.  The question may well get deleted, or migrated, as analysis of this sort isn't what the site is really about. Sorry. Try 'Music Fans'.

Comment: not the guitar plucking, I am talking about the second part of the intro. The one that starts on E major on 9th fret.

Comment: Still all 4/4...

Comment: But he plays 5 chords, E, B , C#, G#, A. After A, he plucks the three top string. So, if i try to count all together it does not fit into 4 beats.

Comment: its just syncopation